# Adding disclosure indicator to tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I believe I'm doing this correctly but it doesn't seem to be working? The text for the cell is written indicating the if statement is correct and is running, However the cell accessory is not changing.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        if ([[tableContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  isEqual: @"New Time"]) {
            cell.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
            cell.textLabel.text = [tableContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
        else{
            cell.textLabel.text = [tableContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [tableContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    return cell;

}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Okay so tried slimming the code down to try and see whats going on, now this crashes when the view is loaded, totally confused as i have another project where this is working perfectly!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UserCells";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not changing, are you saying its not red? Just a heads up, you are using reusable cells, so you could get a cell that was used for `New Time`, for one of the other conditions and therefore the `tintColor`, `selecionStyle` and `accessoryType` will be what ever they were before (hope that makes sense)

Comment: So are you saying i need to change the type of cells to not reusable?

Comment: not at all, just pointing out that you need to be aware of. Are you now saying its not appearing at all? The new snippet always sets it. I'm not clear on what your question actually is

Comment: The tableview in the latest snippet just crashes, and i have no idea why, even when i revert it back to the original code, it still crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the cell `tint color` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` did work:

```
cell.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // whatever you want
```

Comment: Thanks but i need the ability to add the disclosure indicator and would like to know why that isn't working (The disclosure indicator is the right pointing arrow that appears on the right hand side of the cell).

Comment: The cell has a default background color when selected so when you are setting up Tint color it works for you

Comment: This also appears to be doing nothing at all, im thinking something might be wrong with the cell definition maybe, i shall post some more code.

Comment: try to debug and check whether this condition satisfied or not ?

Comment: The condition is satisfied and the code is executed only when the cell is "New Time", just no change on the app. This is really puzzling me, its never done this before.

Comment: I suppose a cleaning and rebuild of the app is not changing anything ? It seems that `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` should not be used when you working with iOS 7 and higher but that does not change anything. 
Do you have a xib or anything in your storyboard that can "hide" the disclosure indicator in your cell ?